# Selecting text in android using Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I am using following code to select data from the paragraph tag(as it skips the data from bold tag), and it's working fine.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        public String data;
        public String url;

        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String ... params){

        data = "";
        url = params[0];       

        try{
             Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
             Elements e = doc.select("p");
             for (Element element : e){
                  if(element!=null){
                       data+=element.ownText();
                       data+='\n';
                       data+='\n';
                  }
             }
        } 
        catch(Exception e){
             // print stack trace
        }
        return data;
    }
```

I have to select data from paragraph tag, which also contains bold tag. Now, how can I select the whole data, without skipping the data of bold tag (data of paragraph and bold tag).

Comment: Include some of your HTML source to make it easier to understand the question, please!

Try otherwise to use the element.text() to get the whole text inside instead of element.ownText();

Comment: view-source:http://www.nahjulbalagha.org/SermonDetail.php?Sermon=1

see this link, I getting data for the paragraph tag, but I want to get the bold tag data too.

Answer (score 0):

The source is not valid HTML.

To get what you want you have to select the `<body>` tag and retrieve it's text.

```
    String data = "";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nahjulbalagha.org/SermonDetail.php?Sermon=1").get();
    Element e = doc.select("body").first();
    data += e.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

using Jsoup you must know that, (your result) is a DOM document. your tag

is hierarchal lower , it is a part of table data "

```
<td> <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion1" --> 

                <b>Creation of Earth and Sky and the birth of Adam. </b><hr><br><p>Praise is due to Allah whose worth cannot be described by speakers, whose bounties cannot be counted by calculators and whose claim (to obedience) cannot be satisfied by those who attempt to do so, whom the height of intellectual courage cannot appreciate, and the divings of understanding cannot reach; He for whose description no limit has been laid down, no eulogy exists, no time is ordained and no duration is fixed.<p>

He brought forth creation through His Omnipotence, dispersed winds through His Compassion, and made firm the shaking earth with rocks. <p>"
```

, 
so if you want to  have also b tag values and p tag values select tag td :

```
Elements e = doc.select("td");
```

Thanks

Comment: well, I have done that before, but it doesn't return the data in the aligned form (the code provided above returns the data in the aligned form. i.e. paragraphs are seperated)

Comment: try:  doc.select("td > b"); or  doc.select("td.b ");